# sqlite import Mac

Tags: macos, sqlite, terminal, diacritics

I've a problem importing data into a sqlite database.
I go like this:

- I receive the `INSERT` queries from a PHP script, which reads a `*.csv` file and then gets analyzed (remove whitespaces, make geocoding from address ...)
- The queries theirself are just fine and syntactically correct
- The charset of the returned queries are UTF-8 (and are shown properly)
- Trying to import on Mac (OS X Snow Leopoard) with `sqlite3 database.sqlite` on Terminal
- Import itself is FINE - but on german umlauts (ä, ü, ö, ß...) the data repeats itself instead of showing the umlaut (e.g. "Seeblickstraße" is inserted as "SeeblickstraSeeblickstrae")...

The encoding from the database is already `UTF-8` - it looks like it's a problem with the Terminal though... when I press "ß" on Terminal (just in `sqlite3`) it repeats the last input...

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried some different things and discovered that the problem is just within the Terminal @ Mac. I tried to copy the queries into an sqlite database on my server (also `sqlite3`, CentOS 5.5) and went just fine.
So - for copying the queries I use now the **SQLite Manager** extension with Firefox. It is not the way I wanted to do it but it looks like it is the only (fast) way to accomplish it on Mac (for me at the moment).

Answer (score 1):

You could also try saving your `INSERT` statement to a file, then calling the `.read <yourfile>` from your sqlite3 command line. I've had similar problems in the past and I found pasting UTF-8 characters in the terminal did not work very well, but when I used the `.read` statement, it worked out.